# Resolution and Substitution Exercise

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

We are Given the Following Rules:

```
∀x∀y∀z(R(x,y)∧R(x,z))=>R(y,z)
∀x∀y(R(x,y)=>∃u(R(u,x)∧R(u,y))
```

Now the question is, Can we prove the following Rule?

```
∀x∀y(R(x,y)=>R(y,x))
```

It's a Multiple Choice question so the choices are:

```
a.True
b.False
c.Sometimes
d.It depends on Skolem constants' values.
```

The Book that contains this question says that the answer is True, But I can't figure it out.
What I've done so far is Turning the Rules into CNF so the first rule would Become:

1) $\neg R(x,y)\lor \neg R(x,z)\lor R(y,z)$

The Second one would become:

2) $\neg R(x_1,y_1)\lor R(f(x_1,y_1),x_1)$

3) $\neg R(x_2,y_2)\lor R(f(x_2,y_2),y_2)$

After that I'm Stuck, I can't Prove the rule mentioned in the question from the following three CNF rules using Substitution or Unification, Am I doing Something Wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to negate the conclusion and add it to your clauses. So, you get:

$\neg \forall x \forall y (R(x,y) \to R(y,x))$

which becomes:

$\exists x \exists y (R(x,y) \land \neg  R(y,x))$

and that gives you:

$R(c1,c2)$

and

$\neg  R(c2,c1)$

So adding those to your clause set, you get:

$1. \neg R(x,y) \lor \neg R(x,z) \lor R(y,z)$

$2. \neg R(x1,y1) \lor R(f(x1,y1),x1)$

$3. \neg R(x2,y2) \lor R(f(x2,y2),y2)$

$4. R(c1,c2)$

$5. \neg R(c2,c1)$

and now you can resolve as follows:

$6. R(f(c1,c2),c1)  \ (2,4)$

$7. R(f(c1,c2),c2) \ (3,4)$

$8. \neg R(f(c1,c2),z) \lor R(c2,z) \ (1,7)$

$9. R(c2,c1) \ (6,8)$

$10. \bot \ (5,9)$

Comment: Then after adding those two clauses and solving the clauses together If I can reach a Nil then the answer is True?? Right??

Comment: @MiriamArbaji Correct! Need some help with that or do you think you can figure that out yourself?

Comment: I'm Still Unable to reach a Nil, I know I can Substitute a variable by a skolem constant, and I Can't Substitue a constant by another Constant Right??

Comment: @MiriamArbaji Correct: you can substitute variables with skolem constants, but you can't substitute constants with Skolem constants.  Try a few more minutes, it's not too hard ....

Comment: Ok I will Thank You a lot

Comment: @MiriamArbaji You're welcome. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

> > $\forall x~\forall y~\forall z~(R(x,y)\land R(x,z)\to R(y,z))$
> >
> > $\forall x~\forall y~(R(x,y)\to ∃u~(R(u,x)∧R(u,y))$
>
> Now the question is, Can we prove the following Rule?
>
> > $\forall x~\forall y~(R(x,y)\to R(y,x))$

Yes.  Moreover, we do not need to actually do so to know it may be done.

The first rule is that if any things have anything that is $R$-related to them, then they will be $R$-related to each other.   Note that conjunction is commutative.

The second rule is that any things $R$-related to each other *will* have some thing that is $R$-related to each of them.

So clearly the relation $R$ is symmetric.

That is all the reasoning that you need to answer such a multi-choice question.

Comment: Thank you so much